# Obtaining prediction equation from principal components analysis using 1st orthogonal component

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

Suppose you've collected data on factors $X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots X_p$ and you're interested in creating a latent factor score $L = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \ldots \beta_p X_p$ . For instance, these variables might have been part of a regimen of pain testing and you wish to "score" individuals for their overall pain sensitivity. How does one extract the $\beta$s as from the question above and calculate their standard errors?

For instance, in R, I can run:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100, 10)
p <- princomp(x)
```

What's the linear equation that gives me the first orthonormal component of the $x$ matrix?

Comment: Just to clarify: By "first orthonormal component" you mean the eigenvector $\psi_1$ of the covariance matrix of `x` with the largest eigenvalue or the corresponding PC projection scores (say $f_{1,j}$)? Cause in that case you are simply minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^N||Y_i - \hat{Y}_i||{^2}$ where $ \hat{Y}_i = f_{1,j} \psi_1$ (so practically you just scale your first PC here) and $N$ your number of samples; $Y_i$ being a row of the matrix $[X_1, \dots X_p]$.

Comment: I think, based on your description, I would like the latter: a formula for the linear combination $\mathbf{X}^T \beta$ of variables that gives the corresponding PC projection score $f_{1, j}$: this can be interpreted as a latent factor score, right? I don't know where I can identify the $\beta$ in the results.

Comment: Hi @AdamO, I would also like to clarify: are you asking about how to extract the coefficients of the linear combination specifically in R (i.e. what should the next line in your code be?), or is it an abstract question on PCA?